# sql in python. what do with strings in sql

Tags: python, postgresql

I am calling SQL in Python and when I try to use a string in SQL it does not consider it as a string because the whole SQL statement in enclosed in `""`. What should I do?

This is my Python code for SQLl. I just want `do_check_id` to be considered as a string here.

```
call.sql("SELECT a.id FROM application a where ed.servicename = 'do_check_id'")
```

Comment: That's a fine string. Does it work? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: Show us more code and what you expect…

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your `do_check_id` string variable inside a sql command consider using of placeholders and prepared statements:

Using [psycopg2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL#Perform_a_Select) to interact with Postgres:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT a.id FROM application a where ed.servicename = %s", do_check_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with string formatting as below.

str_val = 'do_check_id'

call.sql("SELECT a.id FROM application a where ed.servicename = %s" %str_val)

Comment: It would be better to use the `format()` function:

    `call.sql("SELECT a.id FROM application a where ed.servicename = {0}".format(str_val))`

Comment: 1- Strings must be properly quoted in SQL. You can't simply replace them using Python's built-in `%` formatter or the `.format()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your DB driver.

[The sqlite3 driver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) which comes with Python uses `?` for this:

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

Other drivers have similar features.

Don't try to build SQL yourself, there are some pitfalls that may make your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).